# VueJS Simple Alert Appear

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Can someone help me make this simple alert work? What I wanted was if I click the trigger button, the text would appear but then the component should do its part.

I'm new and learning VueJS and now is in the components part but I haven't fully grasped it yet.

Here's the link: [JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/fefatatemi/edit?html,js,console,output)

Snippet of the JS Script

```
Vue.component('alert', {
  template: '#alert',
    props: {
      errors:false
    },
    data: function() {
      return {
        message:""
      }
    },
    methods: {
      appear: function (status) {
        if(status=="yes") {
          errors = true;
          message = "Appeared";
        }
      }
    }
});

var myapp = new Vue({
  components: 'alert',
  el: '#app',
  data: {

  },
  methods: {
    trigger: function() {
      this.$alert.appear("yes");
    }
  }


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your code work the way I *think* you are trying to get it to work I made a few changes.

**Template**

```
<div id=app>
  <button @click="trigger">Trigger</button>
  <alert ref="alert"></alert>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
Vue.component('alert', {
  template: '#alert',
    data: function() {
      return {
        message:"",
        errors: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      appear: function (status) {
        if(status=="yes") {
          this.errors = true;
          this.message = "Appeared";
        }
      }
    }
});

var myapp = new Vue({
  components: 'alert',
  el: '#app',
  data: {

  },
  methods: {
    trigger: function() {
      this.$refs.alert.appear("yes");
    }
  }
})
```

Here is the [updated bin](https://jsbin.com/kofodexoro/1/edit?html,js,console,output).

This is a pretty atypical way to do this kind of thing though. Here is an example of a more idiomatic alert.

```js
Vue.component('alert', {
  props:["message","show"],
  template: '#alert',
});

var myapp = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    errors: false,
    errorMessage: null
  },
  methods: {
    trigger: function() {
      this.errors = true
      this.errorMessage = "Whoops!"
    }
  }
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>

  <div id=app>
    <button @click="trigger">Trigger</button>
    <alert :message="errorMessage" :show="errors"></alert>
  </div>
  
  <template id="alert">
    <div v-show="show">
      <div>{{ message }}</div>
    </div>
  </template>
```

In this second example, the information to show in the alert is passed down to the alert component via *properties* and the alert is also triggered via a property. This is how you would typically do it in Vue.

Comment: What if I have some custom alert message that I wanted the javascript to handle instead of this:

<alert message="appeared" :show="errors"></alert>.

Maybe bootstrap classes for styling and custom messages for the alert, how should I do this?

Comment: @KaySingian I updated the second example to show how you might do that. The message can be passed in as a property. As far as styling, just add the classes to the component. If you wanted to do error, info, success, etc, maybe a third property!